# Identify corrupt .xml files that begins with hex 00 00 00 00

Tags: xml, batch-file, powershell, binary, identify

I have two ways forward at the moment. Either would work but I'm not quite there with the batch programming yet. I sometimes get corrupt .xml files in a folder and need to delete such. When that happens the .xml file consist of only hex 00 00 00 00 00 ....

1. If there is a .xml files that has more than x bytes leading binary zeros it should be deleted.
2. Delete the .xml file with the oldest timestamp in a directory WHEN there are more than x .zip files in the same folder. When there is a corrupt xml in the directory the .zip files are stacking up instead of getting unpacked and deleted.

In Linux I Think I would have been able to fix this but in this Windows machine I would prefer to use only standard batch commands.

Edit: Powershell code would work for me too.

edit2: (fixed it myself with a bit of google help)
certutil -dump %%f | find "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00" && move %%f .\corrupt
slow but works, will probably use the powershell solution below

Thank you for your help
/Per

Comment: Can you post any commands you have tried to use but were unsuccessful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding XML files with leading 0 bytes, you could do something like this:

```
Get-Content foo.xml -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 4 | 
    Where {$_ -ne 0} | Foreach {'Xml is corrupt';break}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works fine if using {$_ -eq 0} but only checks if one of the first 4 bytes is zero. Though that should be enough since there shouldn't be any leading zero bytes in the file.

Comment: You can easily make that `4` a variable e.g. `Get-Content foo.xml -enc byte -TotalCOunt $numBytes`.